# Pivot Not Showing Cross-tab

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm stuck on this:
(1) Getting an error on line 2 regarding 'Invalid column name 'book_id''. I need the book_id listed after the publ_id.
(2) Getting nulls for the max(list_price) values.

```
select publ_id 'Publ'
  , book_id as 'Book'
  , [1] as 'Price1'
  , [2] as 'Price2'
  , [3] as 'Price3'
  , [4] as 'Price4'
from
(
  select publ_id, book_id, title, list_price
  from bkinfo.books 
) tbl   
pivot
( 
  max(list_price) for book_id in([1],[2],[3],[4])
)p
;
go
```

Comment: Are you sure that `book_id` is a column in table `books` ?

Comment: Yes, just double-checked. If I comment out the second line, 'book_id as 'Book'', the query runs but then I get nulls for the data. Weird.

Comment: It's a scope problem: book_id on the second line can't see book_id in the subquery. Trying to figure out the workaround now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code is missing "as":

```
Select publ_id 'Publ'
  , book_id as 'Book
```

This is probably what you should have:

```
Select publ_id as 'Publ'
  , book_id as 'Book
```

Comment: I'm running SQL Server.